# Wireless very slow on one laptop on network, all other machines normal?

Tags: wireless-networking, troubleshooting, connection

My new laptop (Acer Aspire Timeine 3810TZ running Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit) is acting very strange on my wireless network.

Below are the issues I'm noticing...

1. The connection frequently drops. I see the icon change from 'full bars' to 'empty bars with yellow star (meaning no connection)' occasionally.
2. Almost every website I visit (Firefox) hangs for a long time on 'Looking up www.amazon.com' for example. After a long pause, it finally starts loading the website.

Neither of these problems exist on any other machines on my network. I also have a desktop running the same OS wirelessly and it works fine.

I've run several Speedtest.net tests and the speeds are great (20MBit down/4 up). Results from pingtest.net are as follows:

**Line quality: D

Ping: 46ms

Jitter: 65ms

Packet Loss: 9%**

These results are to a server that is less than 10 miles from my residence. The results on the other machines in my house are normal.

Any suggestions? This is becoming very annoying as I purchased this machine primarily for browsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be an interference from another network or device. If that is the case, switching to a different WiFi channel could help.

Comment: Would that still make sense given that none of the other wireless machines in my house have a problem?

Comment: Possibly, if the laptop is in a location in your house that puts it closer to an interfering device, or if it just copes less well with interference than do your other wireless devices.  You might learn something more by checking its performance on some other WiFi network(s) compared to other devices on those networks.